# Usar condicional para verificar as datas caso nao exista em uma coluna busque com o valor nulo

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Tenho as seguintes tabelas na  BD Oracle 11g

```
irrigation
----------------
militet_applied, 
close_date

rainfall
---------------
rain_index, 
reading_date
```

E eu gostaria de fazer um select semelhante a esse:

```
select r.rain_index, 
       i.militet_applied
from irrigation i, rainfall r
```

Mas no meu `where clause` gostaria de fazer o seguinte:
 - Se `r.reading_date = i.close_date` me traga os valores `(i.militet_applied)`, 
   mas tambem se
   `r.reading_date` ser igual/nao tiver na coluna `i.close_cycle`, me traga valores nulos `(i.militet_applied`).

Estou contando com voces nessa duvida.

Comment: Ficou um pouco difícil de entender a segunda parte, a partir do "mas também se...". Essa coluna `i.close_cycle` é uma outra coluna de `irrigation`? Ou isso foi um typo e se refere à própria `i.close_date`?

Comment: e r.reading_date = i.close_date me traga os valores (i.militet_applied), 
mas tambem se r.reading_date ser igual/nao tiver na coluna i.close_cycle, me traga valores nulos (i.militet_applied).

SELECT 
...
(CASE WHEN e r.reading_date = i.close_date THEN i.militet_applied
     ELSE NULL END  mas como disse o @diegofm ficou confuso

Comment: Desculpe pelo erro, sim me referia a i.close_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JosefoSad, apesar da pergunta estar confusa, seguindo a risca o que você informou, uma opção é essa:

```
SELECT 
  R.RAIN_INDEX, 
  CASE 
    WHEN R.READING_DATE = I.CLOSE_CYCLE OR R.READING_DATE NOT IN (SELECT I2.CLOSE_CYCLE FROM IRRIGATION I2) THEN NULL
    ELSE I.MILITET_APPLIED END AS MILITET_APPLIED
FROM 
  RAINFALL R
  JOIN IRRIGATION I ON R.READING_DATE = I.CLOSE_DATE;
```

Caso você queira que a coluna MILITET_APPLIED apenas seja nula quando não existir correspondência na junção (R.READING_DATE = I.CLOSE_DATE), use o LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
  R.RAIN_INDEX, 
  I.MILITET_APPLIED
FROM 
  RAINFALL R
  LEFT JOIN IRRIGATION I ON R.READING_DATE = I.CLOSE_DATE;
```

Comment: Muito agradecido, era exatamente o que queria.